# Simulate an incoming call from a private number

Tags: android, emulation, phone-call

How can I simulate an incoming call from a private number -- in an emulator?

Comment: no caller id? is that what you mean?

Comment: @dldnh Yes it is. And I'll use it in emulator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

connect to your PC using telnet on the port of your emulator, e.g.

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

and use the `gsm call` command with a number of `#` instead of digits

```
gsm call #
```

and you'll receive your unknown call on the emulator's phone.

Comment: Could you please help me with SMS? Can I send a SMS (private number) to emulator?

Comment: unlike a call, an SMS must have a number with it

Comment: This simulates a call from an unknown number but doesn't show the "Private Number" text in the android dialler.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not seems to work out of the box with recent AVD versions, you need the auth token that is stored in `~/.emulator_console_auth_token` on Unix. Maybe you could edit your response?