# What is the incoming call number String value when the call is withheld/unknown?

Tags: android

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens for incoming calls. When a call is incoming, I get the number by doing the following:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
...
String phoneNumber = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
```

What happens when the incoming call is from a withheld number, and **what value is assigned to the phoneNumber string?**

I'm guessing its either `null`, `"unknown"`, `"withheld"`, or something similar, but unfortunately  i haven't found how to simulate incoming calls from a withheld number, so I cannot be sure.

Comment: Have a read of [`Bundle.getString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getString(java.lang.String))

Comment: @Bob. I'm afraid that doesn't help. You are implying that this will return null. But what if it returns UNKNOWN NUMBER or WITHHELD, (like the text you see on your mobile phones screen when you get a call from a withheld number)

Comment: Most phones, at least in the US, are required to have a means to block caller ID information.  Why not call yourself from a blocked phone and see what happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read through the source of `TelephonyRegistry`: [Link](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/TelephonyRegistry.java)

> /** ... this class provides a
>   centralized place that applications can register and be called back
>   from.  */

The broadcast for an incoming call is sent from this method:

```
private void broadcastCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    ....
    ....
    Intent intent = new Intent(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
    intent.putExtra(PhoneConstants.STATE_KEY,
            DefaultPhoneNotifier.convertCallState(state).toString());

    // If `incomingNumber` is empty, the key 
    // `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER` will not be present
    // in the attached Bundle
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(incomingNumber)) {
        intent.putExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER, incomingNumber);
    }
    mContext.sendBroadcastAsUser(intent, UserHandle.ALL,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
}
```

So, you'll receive a value corresponding to `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER` iff `incomingNumber` is not empty.

`incomingNumber` comes from `DefaultPhoneNotifier#notifyPhoneState(Phone)`: [Link](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/DefaultPhoneNotifier.java)

```
@Override
public void notifyPhoneState(Phone sender) {
    Call ringingCall = sender.getRingingCall();
    String incomingNumber = "";
    if (ringingCall != null && ringingCall.getEarliestConnection() != null){

        // Here
        incomingNumber = ringingCall.getEarliestConnection().getAddress();

    }
    try {
        mRegistry.notifyCallState(convertCallState(sender.getState()), incomingNumber);
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        // system process is dead
    }
}
```

`ringingCall.getEarliestConnection().getAddress()` calls the `getAddress()` method from one of the classes that extend `com.android.internal.telephony.Connection` (GsmConnection, CdmaConnection..).

If you look at the constructor of `GsmConnection`, you can see that there are variables assigned for number AND caller name. From what I can tell, as a receiver, you only receive the number - if one is available. So, in case of an empty string (when a caller id is blocked/withheld), the key `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER` will not be present in the `Bundle` you receive.

You did not mention as to why you need this information. If you are trying to show a personalized message by comparing String values, I suggest you do the following:

```
String phoneNumber = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER,
                              "Personalized message for a Blocked Call");
```

I am not sure if this will be an adequate test, but to simulate a blocked caller id, you can take a look at this question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004162/simulate-an-incoming-call-from-a-private-number).